# getItems() and getData(). What is the different?

Tags: magento2

Sometimes, i used function getData() and get a different result with getItems(). what is different of them?

Comment: Thanks mate. +1 for answer acceptance :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
getItems()
```

will return collection in ORM (Object)

where as

```
getData()
```

will return data in array form.

You cannot use any further functions on `getData()` but in `getItems()` you can use further functions.

Like: if you are using cart object, and you use `getItems()` then in `foreach` loop you can use function `$item->getProduct();` but you cannot do this in `getData`

Comment: tks very much sir

Answer (score 3):

```
getData()
```

its return the data in an array based on the filter used on collection.

`getItems()` it returns object list.

`getData()` returns data as an array while `getItems()` returns objectlist.

Comment: tks very much sir

Comment: anytime welcome :)